# Replace a comma with new line in RTF

Tags: vb.net, rtf

I have a Richtextbox that contains text.

For example, it contains `Example1,Example2,Example3`.

I'm wanting it to replace the commas with a newlines, so it should look like this:

```
Example1
Example2
Example3
```

but I don't know how to do this.

I've googled and searched around for this but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Replace(oldStr, newStr)` like this:

```
myRichTextBox.Text = myRichTextBox.Text.Replace(",", vbNewLine)
```

Have fun.

Comment: This removes all formatting from the **rich**textbox.

Comment: @GSerg Isn't that the `.Rtf` property?

Comment: @GSerg You are absolutely right, forget about my last comment.

Comment: This helped with what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

In [RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), the code for the end of a paragraph is `\par` followed by a delimiter, which may as well be a space for this purpose. So you can use:

```
RTB1.Rtf = RTB1.Rtf.Replace(",", "\par ")
```